# Laravel hasMany relationship returning huge amounts of data which is not a collection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship

I am working on a very simple API using laravel. Users have many tasks, and a task belongs to a user. My routes file is as follows :

```
<?php

Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
Route::get('users/{user_id}/tasks', 'UsersController@show_tasks');
Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
```

I want that the second route gets all the tasks related to that particular user. It is simple. I just added a relationship in my User model as follows :

```
public function tasks(){
        return $this->hasMany('Task');
    }
```

And the `show_tasks` method in my `UsersController` is as follows :

```
public function show_tasks($id){

    if(!$user = $this->user->find($id)){
        return Acme::response('error', 'Resource not found.', [], 404);
    }

    $tasks = $user->tasks();
    dd($tasks);

    return Acme::response('success', [], $tasks, 200);
}
```

I have placed the dd method because the response was returning an empty array and I wanted to see what is in the `$tasks` variable first hand. I thought it must be a collection object but when I ran this in my Postman REST client, it hanged due to the large data overflow I am assuming, screenshot below :

[image: Output from the dd method call!]

If anyone is curious about the `Acme::response` method, I am also including that code :

```
public static function response($status = [], $messages = [], $data = [], $httpStatusCode){
        return Response::json([
            'status' => $status,
            'messages' => $messages,
            'data' => $data,
        ], $httpStatusCode);
    }
```

Why is the relationship not working? I have been this for hours and still can't figure out why! I am guessing I might be doing a very silly mistake somewhere but can't get to it anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `()` here. Instead of:

```
$tasks = $user->tasks();
```

you will get your tasks using:

```
$tasks = $user->tasks;
```

**EDIT**

When you have relation and you use `$user->tasks` it works as you would use `$user->tasks()->get()` so we can say it's a shortcut.

You could use parantheses you get relation you can add more conditions, for example you could do something like that:

```
$tasks = $user->tasks()->active()->get();
```

and define scope in your `Task` model:

```
function activeScope($q) {
  return $q->where('status',1);
}
```

And now you can get only active tasks for user.

Comment: Haha, I knew I was doing something silly! Thank you! Will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Anyway, can you explain the unlimited flow of data I saw when I used tasks() instead of task?

Comment: @Rohan I've added more details